# How to prove an ideal is not principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I've just asked this question in another post, but I'm reposting it here since it wasn't the only question there and it was suggested to me to  ask just one question per post.

I would like to know if there is a generic method to prove or disprove that an ideal is principal. Before closing the question, someone commented that there isn't a single way to do it, so if that's the case I would like some review on two exercises I was given, where the ideals are in $\Bbb Z[X]$.

$(5, X^2 +3)$: I believe this ideal to not be principal, as if it were principal then the generator would need to be of degree $0$ to generate $5$, but $5$ is irreducible so it can only be generated by $1$ or $5$. The number $5$ cannot be a generator since $X^2 +3$ is in the ideal, but it also cannot be $1$ as the ideal is different from $\Bbb Z[X]$, for example $X$ is not in it,

$(X^2 +1, X+2)$: I believe this ideal to also not be principal. Those polynomials are irreducible and not associate, so if the ideal were to be generated by one element it would need to be a unit. But the remainder of division of $X^2+1$ by $X+2$ is $5$, so every constant in this ideal is multiple of $5$ and so the ideal is different from $\Bbb Z[X]$.

Are there some mistakes?

Comment: There is at least a helpful collection here available, how to prove this in certain cases. Let me just link one post as an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008599/is-i-langle-5-x2-rangle-a-principal-ideal-or-not-in-bbb-zx?rq=1), which was asked for an exam preparation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no general method, but here are suggestions in two cases: $\mathbf Z[x]$ and $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$.

Let $I$ be an ideal in $\mathbf Z[x]$.  Every ideal in $\mathbf Z[x]$ is finitely generated (and your two examples are even explicitly defined with two generators each), so we can write $I = (f_1,\ldots,f_r)$.
Let $d$ be the gcd of $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$, which could be computed using irreducible factorizations of the $f_i$'s since $\mathbf Z[x]$ has unique factorization. This gcd is determined up to sign.

**Claim**: if $I$ is principal then $d$ must be a generator of $I$.

To prove the claim; suppose $I = (g)$. Then from $f_i \in I$ we have $f_i \in (g)$, so $g \mid f_i$ for all $i$. Thus $g \mid d$ by properties of unique factorization domains.

Since $g \in I = (f_1,\ldots,f_r)$, we have $g = f_1h_1+\cdots+f_rh_r$ for some $h_i$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$. Then $d$ dividing each $f_i$ implies $d \mid g$. That together with $g \mid d$ tells us $g = \pm d$, so $I = (g) = (d)$.  This concludes the proof of the claim.

Your two examples are $(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$ where $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are relatively prime in $\mathbf Z[x]$. Therefore $\gcd(f_1(x),f_2(x)) = 1$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$.  So if the ideal $(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$ is principal then it must be $(1)$.  Now it remains to check that $1 \not\in (f_1(x),f_2(x))$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$ in your two examples.

While ideals in $\mathbf Z[x]$ are not always principal, ideals in $\mathbf Q[x]$ are all principal and we can extend ideals in $\mathbf Z[x]$ to ideals in $\mathbf Q[x]$. When $A$ is a ring contained in a ring $B$ (like $\mathbf Z$ contained in $\mathbf Q$) each ideal $I$ in $A$ has an extension $IB$ to an ideal in $B$ that is defined to be the smallest ideal in $B$ containing $I$. Check

(i) $IB$ consists of all sums $\sum_{k=1}^n i_kb_k$ where $n \geq 1$, $i_k \in I$, and $b_k \in B$,

(ii) when $I = aA$ we have $IB = aB$,

(iii) when $I = a_1A + \cdots + a_mA$, we have $IB = a_1B + \cdots + a_mB$.

We can abbreviate (ii) and (iii) to $I = (a) \Rightarrow IB = (a)$ and $I = (a_1,\ldots,a_m) \Rightarrow IB = (a_1,\ldots,a_m)$, where you're expected to realize that the parentheses in the descriptions of $IB$ mean ideals generated in $B$ rather than in $A$.

**Example**.  If $I = (2,x)$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$, then $I \not= \mathbf Z[x]$ since $1 \not\in I$, as all constants in $I$ are even, but $I\mathbf Q[x] = (2,x) = \mathbf Q[x]$ since $2$ is a unit in $\mathbf Q[x]$.

Starting with an ideal $I = (f_1(x),\ldots,f_r(x))$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$, its extended ideal $I\mathbf Q[x]$ *must* be principal because $\mathbf Q[x]$ is a PID. Then $I = (f(x))$ for some $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Q[x]$. By (iii) above, $I\mathbf Q[x] = (f_1,\ldots,f_r)\mathbf Q[x]$, so by the same argument used in $\mathbf Z[x]$ we know $f$ has to be the gcd of the $f_i$'s in $\mathbf Q[x]$, which is determined up to a nonzero constant multiple. Every nonzero polynomial in $\mathbf Q[x]$ has a constant multiple that is a primitive polynomial in $\mathbf Z[x]$, so we can take $f$ to be the gcd of $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ in $\mathbf Q[x]$ that's primitive in $\mathbf Z[x]$.

Suppose $I = (f_1,\ldots,f_r)$ is principal in $\mathbf Z[x]$, so $I = d\mathbf Z[x]$ where $d$ is the $\mathbf Z[x]$-gcd of $f_1,\ldots,f_r$. Then $(d) = (f)$ as ideals in $\mathbf Q[x]$, so
$d = sf$ where $s \in \mathbf Q^\times$. Write $s$ in reduced form as $m/n$. Then $nd = mf$, an equation in $\mathbf Z[x]$. Compute the content (gcd of coefficients) of both sides:
$n\,{\rm cont}(d) = m\,{\rm cont}(f) = m$ in $\mathbf Z$ since $f$ is primitive, so ${\rm cont}(d) = m/n = s$.
Thus $d = sf = {\rm cont}(d)f$. If some $f_i$ is primitive then $d$, a factor of $f_i$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$, is also primitive, so ${\rm cont}(d) = 1$ and thus $d = f$: if $I$ is principal and some $f_i$ is primitive then $I$ must be generated as an ideal in $\mathbf Z[x]$ by the $\mathbf Q[x]$-gcd of the $f_i$'s that is scaled to be primitive in $\mathbf Z[x]$.

Everything I wrote about $\mathbf Z[x]$ carries over to $R[x]$ when $R$ has unique factorization.

Now let's look at a different family of rings: $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ where $d$ is an integer that is not a perfect square.

Two key facts: (i) every nonzero ideal $I$ in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ has finite index (meaning the quotient ring $\mathbf Z[x]/I$ is finite) and (ii) each nonzero principal ideal $(a+b\sqrt{d})$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, has index $|a^2 - db^2|$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$.

Here is how you can prove (i): pick a nonzero element $a+b\sqrt{d}$ in $I$. Then its norm $n := (a+b\sqrt{d})(a-b\sqrt{d})$ is a nonzero integer that's also in $I$ and $(n) \subset I \subset \mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$, so it suffices to prove principal ideals $(n)$ with nonzero $n$ in $\mathbf Z$ have finite index in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ and that follows from writing $(n) = \mathbf Z{n} + \mathbf Z{n}\sqrt{d}$, since it implies $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]/(n) \cong (\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^2$ as *additive groups* (not as rings!) and thus $(n)$ has index $n^2$ in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$.

Here is how you can prove (ii): when $I = (a+b\sqrt{d})$, set $n = (a+b\sqrt{d})(a-b\sqrt{d})$.  Then $(n) \subset I \subset \mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$, so
$$
n^2 = [\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:(n)] = [\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:I][I:(n)],
$$
where $[I:(n)]$ is the cardinality of the quotient group $I/(n) = (a+b\sqrt{d})/((a+b\sqrt{d})(a-b\sqrt{d}))$. In any integral domain $R$, with nonzero elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\alpha R/(\alpha\beta)R \cong R/\beta R$ as additive groups, so $I/(n) \cong \mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]/(a-b\sqrt{d})$. The conjugation mapping $x+y\sqrt{d} \mapsto x-y\sqrt{d}$ is a ring automorphism of $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ that sends the ideal $(a+b\sqrt{d})$ to the ideal $(a-b\sqrt{d})$, so conjugation induces a ring isomorphism from $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]/(a+b\sqrt{d})$ to $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]/(a-b\sqrt{d})$. Thus $[\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:(a-b\sqrt{d})] = [\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:(a+b\sqrt{d})]$, so $[I:(n)] = [\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:(a-b\sqrt{d})] = [\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:(a+b\sqrt{d})]$. Hence
$$
n^2 = [\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:(n)] = [\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:I][I:(n)] = [\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:I]^2.
$$
Now take square roots to get $[\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]:I] = |n|$.

Back to the general setting, when $I$ is a nonzero ideal in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ with index $n$, in order that $I$ be principal we have to be able to solve the equation $x^2 - dy^2 = n$ or $x^2 - dy^2 = -n$ in integers $x$ and $y$. So if those two equations  have no integral solutions, then $I$ is not principal.

**Example**.  In $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{5}]$ the ideal $I = (2,1+\sqrt{5})$ turns out to have index $2$, but the equations $x^2 - 5y^2 = \pm 2$ have no integral solutions because they have no solutions mod $5$. Thus the ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{5})$ in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{5}]$ is nonprincipal.

Theorem 3.3 and examples in Section 4 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf) show you how to determine whether $x^2 - dy^2 = \pm n$ has an integral solution without having to rely on the modular arithmetic trick above.

Comment: So much information, thank you very much! Some of the concept you wrote about are new to me, so let me ask if i got them right: the extension of an ideal is just the same ideal as before, but to be seen inside Q[x] (and so it must gain new elements by absorption of product), correct? I've also never heard of index of an ideal, but a quick search online says it's the cardinality of R/I, is it right? It would make sense as it is the same definition of index of a subgroup.

Comment: I added some more detail to my answer to address your questions. The notion of index is in the sense of group theory.

Comment: Thank you again, your answer has been very exhaustive and I appreciate all the extra steps you have added. The part on Z[sqrtd] is probably a little to advanced for what I'm doing now (I've never been asked to solve integer non linear equation yet), but in case of small value of d where i can just do the mod d and check the answers it's a nice tool to have!